# Devise post-registration redirect based on hidden field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I've got a registration form; after the account has been created, I want to choose where the user is redirected to based upon a hidden field that was on the original registration form. I'm not storing this field in the database.

What strategy should I use?

Answer (score 0):

Your hidden field should be passed to your controller as a parameter. You can access it using something like:

```
params[:hidden_field_name]
```

If you define after_sign_up_path_for(resource) in your ApplicationController, you should be able to use the parameter to redirect the user accordingly:

```
  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    if params[:hidden_field_name] == "example"
      example_path # as defined in config/routes.rb
    elsif params[:hidden_field_name] == "example2"
      example2_path
    end
  end
```

You can check out lines 15-29 and 86-88 here for more information: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question at all; the question relates to devise, not passing parameters.

Comment: I added some more devise-specific information. I have used this method to override after_sign_in_path_for, but never after_sign_up_path_for, but it should be the same idea! Hope it helps.